# Giroscopio no android studio

Tags: android

Como utilizar o Giroscopio no android studio para saber em qual direção o veiculo com o dispositivo está andando? Através do GPS.

Comment: Comece por [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro), se depois tiver alguma dúvida mais concreta faça uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Link não está abrindo.

Comment: Ainda agora o abri: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro

Comment: Error 404.  ! File not Found

Comment: Apenas para teste, Aqui abriu os dois inks!

Comment: Para mim, os dois links também abrem.